# smart pointer to function

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to create smart pointer to my function.

I have the function:

```
double returnValue(int i){
       return i;
}
```

Its pretty simple to create raw pointer:

```
double (*somePTR)(int) = &returnValue;
```

But how to make smart pointer to the function, for example `shared_ptr`?

```
auto someptr = std::make_shared<double>(&returnValue);
```

I have tried a lot of of options, but nothing works.

Comment: Huh? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Why would you want a smart pointer to a function? You can't create or destroy a function...

Comment: You need to understand first what smart pointers were created for.

Comment: why do you think you need this?

Comment: I wanted to make a few functions and then put the pointers of them to the vector and later use some functions while creating new objects.

Comment: This is a handy way to package up a lambda wrapped up as a `std::function<>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you mean a smart function pointer, and for that there is since C++11, `std::function`, so how about this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

double a(int i){
    return i;
}

double b(int i){
    return i * 2;
}

double c(double d, int i){
    return i - d;
}


int main() {
    std::function<double(int)> func = a;
    std::cout << func(42) << std::endl;//Output 42

    func = b;
    std::cout << func(42) << std::endl;//Output 84

    //func = c; //Error since c has a different signature (need one more argument), #type safety

    func = std::bind(c, 5 ,std::placeholders::_1); //func stores the needed 2nd argument
    std::cout << func(42) << std::endl;//Output 37

}
```

Comment: Congrats on guessing what the OP intended!

Comment: Usually I flag or downvote such ambiguous questions, but since his/her intention was to improve code quality/safety and also that he/she was referring to function pointers, it was easy ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. Smart pointers are only for object pointers not function pointers.

The intent behind smart pointers is to manage dynamically allocated memory. If a smart pointer is able to determine the dynamically allocated memory can be deallocated, it does that.

There is no such thing for function pointers.

Answer (score 3):

**Smart pointers exist to manage the data behind the address.**

In case of a function pointer this data is program code. If the pointer runs out of scope it can't just *delete the function*.

Smart pointers can't hold function addresses because there wouldn't be any reason for them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can not do that. Since you don't do memory management, like allocate dynamic memory or destroy a function when it goes out of scope, for example, it does not make sense to have a smart pointer for that. Have first a look to the intention of smart pointers and when would you use them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about use-case, maybe it is needed only because of some uniformity in processing.

`shared_ptr<>` cannot contain a pointer to function, but can contain a dynamically allocated pointer to pointer to a function:

```
double f(int i) { return i; }
typedef double(*f_ptr)(int i);

int main (int _argc, char const **_argv) {
  std::shared_ptr<f_ptr> s(new f_ptr(f));
  (*s)(2);   // okay
  s.reset();   // releases a pointer to pointer, not function
  // ...
}
```